In spark sql, is it logical to use percentile_approx on top on percentile_approx?
I have a monthly datasets which is generated from daily. I have a derived attribute which uses percentile_approx function.
Question : I have to build a quarterly datasets.Is it logical to use monthly derived attributes or I have to derive from daily. From monthly, it will be like percentile_approx(percentile_approx(daily data)).
Regards
Sanjeeb
